# Interpreting clustering metrics

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm doing clustering by k-means in Scikit-learn on 398 samples, 306 features. The features matrix is sparse, and the number of clusters is 4.
To improve the clustering, I tried two approaches:

1. After clustering, I used ExtraTreesClassifier() to classify and compute feature importances (samples labeled in clustering)
2. I used PCA to reduce the feature dimension to 2.
   I have computed the following metrics ([SS,](https://github.com/scampion/scikit-learn/blob/master/scikits/learn/cluster/__init__.py) [CH](https://github.com/scampion/scikit-learn/blob/master/scikits/learn/cluster/__init__.py), [SH](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html))

   ```
       Method                   sum_of_squares, Calinski_Harabasz, Silhouette

       1 kmeans                    31.682        401.3            0.879
       2 kmeans+top-features       5989230.351   75863584.45      0.977
       3 kmeans+PCA                890.5431893   58479.00277      0.993
   ```

My questions are:

1. As far as I know, if sum of squares is smaller, the performance of clustering method is better, while if Silhouette is close to 1 the performance of clustering method is better. For instance in the last row both sum of squares and Silhouette are increased compared to the first row.
2. How can I choose which approach has better performance?

Comment: SInce this is a question about cluster diagnostics, I think it's more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* compare sum-of-squares and similar metrics across different projections, transformations or data sets.

To see why, simply multiply every feature by 0.5 - your SSQ will drop by 0.25. So to "improve" your data set, you just need to scale it to a tiny size...

These metrics *must* only be used on the exact same input and parameters. You can't even use sum-of-squares to compare k-means with different k, because the larger k will win. All you can do is multiple random attempts, and then keep the best minimum you found this way.

Answer (score 1):

With 306 features you are under the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). Clustering in 306 dimensions is not meaningful. Therefore I wouldn't select features *after* clustering.

To get interpretable results, you *need* to reduce dimensionality. For 398 samples you need low dimension (2, 3, maybe 4). Your PCA with dimension 2 is good. You can try 3.

An approach with selecting important features before clustering may be problematic. Anyway, are 2/3/4 "best" features meaningful in your case?

Comment: Thank you. I did the same. Now, I normalized the features, then I used PCA for dimension reduction to 4. The resulted PCA components, cover 58% variance of the features.